# Why does my matplotlib bar diagram change when I am running the same python code but in a for-loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

The same code, but written in different ways, gives me different results.

I want to draw a stacked bar in matplotlib. And it draws perfectly when I do not use for-loop.

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
plt.subplot(221)

plt.bar (prod_names, x[0], label=age_names[0])
plt.bar (prod_names, x[1], bottom=x[0], label=age_names[1])
plt.bar (prod_names, x[2], bottom=x[1] + x[0], label=age_names[2])
plt.bar (prod_names, x[3], bottom=x[2] + x[1] + x[0], label=age_names[3])
plt.bar (prod_names, x[4], bottom=x[3] + x[2] + x[1] + x[0], label=age_names[4])
plt.bar (prod_names, x[5], bottom=x[4] + x[3] + x[2] + x[1] + x[0], label=age_names[5])

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
```

Good bar:

[image: Good bar]

But, when I run:

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
plt.subplot(221)

for i in range(6):
    bottom = [0]*len(x[0])
    for j in range (i):
        bottom += x[j]
    plt.bar (prod_names, x[i], bottom, label=age_names[i])


plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
```

I get bad bar:

[image: Good bar]

Comment: It's not the same code. Note the difference between `plt.bar(x,y,bottom)` and `plt.bar(x,y, bottom=bottom)`

Comment: Use `plt.bar (prod_names, x[i], bottom=bottom, label=age_names[i])`

Comment: plt.bar (prod_names, x[i], bottom=bottom, label=age_names[i]) this worked. thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your variable, the third place is for width, so it is using your `bottom` variable to decide the widths of the bars instead of the height of their bases. So if you just change the following line it should work:

```
plt.bar(prod_names, x[i], bottom=bottom, label=age_names[i])
```